# Regex help to find a text is not linked in xml

Tags: c#, regex

I Need Some Regular expression help in c# finding non linked chapters

in this bellow example chapter 7 is linked but chapter 6 and chapter II are not linked i want to find those who not linked (some other cases listed in code).

xml example:

```
...
<p class="text_noindent"><a id="page_47"/>Much of this will
be explained further in the <a xref="ch007">chapter 7</a>context of the charity fashion
show described in Chapter 6. Chapters II</p>
...
```

my code to find this is

```
Regex.Matches(chk.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", ""), "[^<>/\"]\\s*(figure|table|fig.|tab.|chapters|chapter|chap.|cap.|part|figures|tables|chapters|figs.|tabs.)\\s[0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex.Matches(chk.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", ""), "[^<>/\"]\\s*(figure|table|fig.|tab.|chapters|chapter|chap.|cap.|part|figures|tables|chapters|figs.|tabs.)\\s(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[^a-zA-Z0-9]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but its select options like 
scape 1,
stab 
stable
...
etc word also can any one suggest me best solution
  also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better option to select whole words is to surround the pattern with `\b`, like this

```
\b(chap|chapter|etc)\s+[0-9]+\b
```

this will also exclude punctation etc., so you not need to exclude `[^<>"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are trying to match white spaces using `\s*`, but visual studio shows you an error "Unrecognized escape sequence", so you escaped it this way `\\s*`, which meaning is totally different. Try using `[ ]*?` or just white space instead

Comment: space is not an issue its detecting spaces i need to match exact word specified in regex with numeric and roman number followed by that words.

Comment: The space IS the issue, as regex recognizes your `\\s` as a literal `s`, not a whitespace.

Comment: @user1761398 it could be the reason, why stab or stable are found. And what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

When working with regex, you should use the @ like this :

```
String _s = @"\s*";
```

for the example.

I let you change your own code accordingly.